# What exactly is happening under the hood when circular dependency exists?

Tags: scala

When running the following code,

```
object Foo {
  val hoge = Hoge
}

sealed abstract class Hoge(
    val foo: Foo.type = Foo
)

object Hoge {

  case object A extends Hoge

  case object B extends Hoge

  case object C extends Hoge

  val values = IndexedSeq(A, B, C)

}

object Main extends App {
  println(Hoge.B)
  println(Hoge.A)
  println(Hoge.C)
  println(Hoge.values)
}
```

the output is

```
B
A
C
Vector(A, null, C)
```

but changing the main  to

```
object Main extends App {
  println(Hoge.values)
}
```

results in

```
Vector(A, B, C)
```

What exactly is happening under the hood that causes this behaviour?

Answer (score 3):

Objects are lazily initialized. So they are nulls that are later on initialized to some value, and if during their initialization something wanted to get their value it would get null instead.

So what happens here is:

- `Foo` and `Hoge` instances are `null`s
- you request object `Hoge.B` which should require initialization of `Hoge`, then `B`, but in fact it can initialize `B` without initializing the rest of `Hoge` as they are separate objects after all
- however `B` requires initialization of `Foo` (because of that **non-lazy** `val`)
- while `Foo` requires initialization of `Hoge`
- at this point `A`, `B`, `C` and `values` are all `null`s though `B` is **being initialized** - depending on circumstances such circular dependency ends up with either stack overflow or obtaining a null reference
- here we have the latter case, so `A` and `C` gets initialized (because `values` ask for them), `B` is waiting for its dependencies to end initializing, and `values` is initialized with whatever values are there at the moment it is initialized - `B` still being `null`
- with that you end up with all values initialized: `A`, `B`, `C`, `values` where values the last one is made of `A, null, C`

In other words lazy implementation of object is something like:

```
if (!initiailization) { // check flag
  initialization = true
  value = initialize()
}
value
```

without any synchronization. If you access value when initialization is still in progress you skip the recursive call and fetch `null`.

Your second example doesn't create this circular dependency case, so it prints fine.

One way to solve this particular issue would be deferring initialization of `values`, e.g. by making it `lazy val` ([see example](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/PJ05cvzcQAmjczPSeYvrmw)). However each time you add `lazy` you might solve one issue by creating another, so it makes sense to use it carefully and avoid using lazy and circular dependencies.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation.  Shouldn't `println(Hoge.B)` print also `null` ? Why does `Hoge.B` get a non null value, but `B` in `values` doesn't? Swapping the line `println(Hoge.B)` with `println(Hoge.values)` can fix this issue for some reason...

Comment: `Hoge.B` is `null` _during it's initialization_. If anything calls it before original initialization returned its null. After that it always uses returned value. `A` and `C` doesn't have to go full circular-dependency cycle, though it could be worth checking if their `foo` instance isn't `null` thanks to that.

Comment: I am not sure If I understand correctly. _`Hoge.B` is null during it's initialization_ doesn't this mean that at the line of `println(Hoge.B)` should also print `null` instead of `B` as it is in process of being initialized?

Comment: When value is passed to `println` all `object`s are already initialized.